# Inserting record violates two unique indices in PostgreSQL. Which one is checked first?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I have a PostgreSQL table with two unique indices on different fields (`nickname` and `email`). I'm trying to insert a record which violates both constraints. I want that `nickname` is checked and reported first.

I observed that the index that was created first is checked first, so I create the index on `nickname` first and it kind of works. But is that behavior specified and can I rely upon it, or is it only by chance?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL uses [`RelationGetIndexList`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/cache/relcache.c;h=eba77491fd568582690f717549e5b36f2d718f3e;hb=HEAD#l4235) to get the list of indexes, and the comment says:

```
/*
 * RelationGetIndexList -- get a list of OIDs of indexes on this relation
[...]
 *
 * The returned list is guaranteed to be sorted in order by OID.  This is
 * needed by the executor, since for index types that we obtain exclusive
 * locks on when updating the index, all backends must lock the indexes in
 * the same order or we will get deadlocks (see ExecOpenIndices()).  Any
 * consistent ordering would do, but ordering by OID is easy.
[...]
 */
```

OIDs (object identifiers) are 4-byte unsigned integers that are counted up, so normally later objects will get higher OIDs. This corresponds to what you observe.

However, once the range of OIDs is exhausted, they wrap around and start again at `FirstNormalObjectId` (16384), so there is no guarantee that the index that was created first has the lower OID.

You could use a query like:

```
SELECT 'indexname'::regclass::oid;
```

to find the OID of each index.

To get the OID of all indexes on a table, use

```
SELECT indexrelid AS oid, indexrelid::regclass
FROM pg_index
WHERE indrelid = 'tablename'::regclass;
```

Comment: Thanks! A sort of extension for the question then: is there a way to obtain the OIDs for indices via SQL? This way I'll be able to assert that all is ok (or not ok).

Comment: I added a query to the answer.